# Either the websocket or the tornado goes down everytime.

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am new to asynchronous programming. I have been using python 3.5 asyncio for a few days. I wanted to make a server capable of receiving data from a websocket machine client (GPS) as well as rendering a html page as the browser client for the websocket server. I have used websockets for the connection between my machine client and server at port 8765. For rendering the webpage I have used tornado at port 8888 (The html file is at ./views/index.html ). The code works fine for only the websocket server. When I added the tornado server, the code behaved weird and I don't know why. There must be something with the asyncio usage. If I place

```
app = make_app()
app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

just before

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

, the websocket server doesn't connect. If I do the reverse, the tornado server doesn't run.

Please help me out as I am new to asynchronous programming. The server.py, index.html and the client.py (machine clients) are given below.

server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.ioloop 
import tornado.web 

import asyncio
import websockets

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("./views/index.html", title = "GPS")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

clients = []

async def hello(websocket, path):
    clients.append(websocket)
    while True:
        name = await websocket.recv()
        print("< {}".format(name))

        print(clients)
        greeting = "Hello {}!".format(name)
        for each in clients:


            await each.send(greeting)
            print("> {}".format(greeting))

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)
print("Listening on *8765")

app = make_app()
app.listen(8888)
print("APP is listening on *8888")

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import serial
import time 
import asyncio
import websockets

ser =serial.Serial("/dev/tty.usbmodem1421", 9600, timeout=1)

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        while True:
            data = await retrieve()
            await websocket.send(data)
            print("> {}".format(data))
            greeting = await websocket.recv()
            print("< {}".format(data))


async def retrieve():
        data = ser.readline()
        return data #return the location from your example

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

./views/index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{ title }}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765/"),
            messages = document.createElement('ul');
            ws.onopen = function(){
              ws.send("Hello From Browser")
            }
            ws.onmessage = function (event) {

            var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
                message = document.createElement('li'),
                content = document.createTextNode(event.data);
            message.appendChild(content);
            messages.appendChild(message);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(messages);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only run one event loop at a time (unless you give each one its own thread, but that's significantly more complicated). Fortunately, there's a bridge between Tornado and asyncio to let them share the same IOLoop.

Early in your program (before any tornado-related code like `app = make_app()`), do this:

```
import tornado.platform.asyncio
tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
```

and do not call `IOLoop.current().start()`. This will redirect all Tornado-using components to use the asyncio event loop instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Looking forward to work with more asynchronous programs. :)